# What are the quickest ways to reload Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome extensions often either crash, develop memory leaks, etc. Restarting them is slow: open task manager (no keyboard shortcut on Mac), locate, click 'End process'. Are there any quicker ways?

Comment: > you can probably assign something like Ctrl+Shift+Esc to the Chrome task manager

Can't see how on macOS alas